# Looking for Android music player that can sync with desktop ( osx / linux )

Tags: linux, android, osx, audio, media-player

I am currently using Clementine on OSX and Ubuntu - quite happy with it, the gpodder.net integration seems very useful. Gpodder.net is also supported on Android app AntennaPod, so far so ok ;)

I'd like to find a music app that will allow syncing of playlists and allow copying over of songs - in a perfect world it would also sync ratings, tags and play counts. In a magic near-future world it would also let me stream songs to my phone from the desktop client.

Please suggest Apps that at least allow playlist / song syncing, preferably both with osx and linux.

Comment: Must that necessarily be done by the player app? The music files as well as playlists are stored in the file system, so you could use any sync app to synchronize them with your desktop. Unless your player app stores all those details in its own database only, that is.

Comment: @Izzy That seems too tedious to actually do for any length of time - my desktop collection wouldn't fit on my phone - also, I believe that most apps use their own way of dealing with number of plays and ratings, it if were always embedded in a compatible way in the meta-data of the file then it might work.

Comment: As for the Metadata, that would be IDv3. Just playlists naturally cannot go there :)